# CSS Modules - Mark/wrap whole file in :global

Tags: react-css-modules

I have a huge complicated file, I don't want to go to each line and add `:global(.......)`. Is it possible to mark the whole file global?

Comment: I think you made a typo, “:gobal(.......)” should be “:global(.......)”

Comment: Oops thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `:global` on each class to say that you are referring to the global instance of it. There is no other way =/

But if you need to override a lot of global classes, it probably means that the application CSS structure should be refactored or your components should be different.

If you are using React, you can try to do similar to Material-UI: https://v4.mui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes

Your component can receive a prop `classes`, that would receive an object with the CSS classes of your parent component module and apply it internally at the desired specific part of it (root, label, and so on).
So, your parent component can pass the local CSS class as prop to the child component, without needing to override any global CSS.